# What does the ~ symbol means in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Like Select ~'ColumName' from 'TableName'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is the bitwise inversion operator.  So a series of bits such as:

```
01001101
```

is transformed to:

```
10110010
```

It is explained in the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-invert).

Answer (score 0):

The `~` is logical negation and will invert all bytes of the data. While `SELECT 0;` results in 8 bytes of zeros, `SELECT ~0` will result in eight bytes of ones.